# How to get literal class for generic type?

Tags: java, generics, annotations

I've an annotation which need an adaptator class:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ConfigurationAnnotation {

  Class<? extends AdaptatorAbstract<?>> adaptator() default AnAdaptator.class;
}
```

One of these adaptator need to have generic type as following:

```
public class ListEnumAdaptator<T extends Enum<T>> extends AdaptatorAbstract<T> {

  private final Class<T> clazz;

  public ListEnumAdaptator(Class<T> c) {
    this.clazz = c;
  }

  @Override
  public T adaptValue(String k, String v)  {
    return Enum.valueOf(clazz, v);
  }

  public static Class<? extends ListEnumAdaptator<?>> forClass(Class<? extends Enum<?>> c) {
    return new ListEnumAdaptator(c).clazz;
  }
}
```

I create the static method in order to use into the annotation. I thought I could do:

```
@ConfigurationAnnotation(adaptator = ListEnumAdaptator.forClass(AnEnum.class))
```

But I got the following error:

```
// The value for annotation attribute ConfigurationAnnotation.adaptator must be a class literal
```

Is there some way to get "class literal" of genric class?

For exemple I would like a class literal for the type `ListEnumAdaptator<AnEnum>`.

EDIT :

AnAdaptator definition:

```
public class AnAdaptator extends AdaptatorAbstract<Object> {

  @Override
  public Object adaptValue(final String k, final String v) throws Exception {
    throw new Exception("No Adaptator is configured for " + k);
  }

}
```

Comment: There is no way to do that.  Similarly, there is no `Class<List<String>>`, only `Class<List<?>>`.

Comment: Could you share the declaration of AnAdapter please?

Comment: @VasiliyVlasov The default class AnAdapter do nothing and throw an exception (I update the question)